# Entity Framework Eager Loading Multiple Levels Exception

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Ok, so according to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx), the Entity Framework should eagerly load multiple levels by using a `Select` within the `Include` method.

I have the following code:

```
var reports = _context.Reports
    .Include(rt => rt.Fields)
    .Include(rt => rt.Fields.Select(f => f.FieldType))
    .Include(rt => rt.Fields.Select(f => f.FieldType.FieldIdentifier));
```

Yet this throws an `InvalidOperationException` - "Invalid type of expression" on the call to the second include. The Exception is coming from `EntityFrameworkHelper.CollectRelationalMemebers`.

I also tried using strings to `Include` related properties, but that failed as well (I'd rather avoid using the strings if at all possible).

I'm using the EF 5.0 DLL for .NET 4.0. My EF classes are old-fashioned database-first `EntityObject`s.

Does anyone know the cause and if there's anything I can do about this exception?

EDIT:

When using the string version:

```
var reports = _context.Reports
    .Include("Fields")
    .Include("Fields.FieldType")
    .Include("Fields.FieldType.FieldIdentifier"));
```

It throws `InvalidOperationException` - Invalid type of Expression.

Comment: What is the exact exception message when you use the string-based version of `Include`?

Comment: I meant the exception for the **string** based version of `Include`.

Comment: Sorry, that was dumb. I just had pasted the wrong code into the second example. That is the exception for the string based version.

Comment: The exception is really "*Invalid type of expression*" for the **string** version? That's strange because a string is not an expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being that a 3rd party `Include` extension method in a DLL we had be using was getting precedence over the Entity Framework's `Include`. The 3rd party one was throwing the exceptions. After removing it the issue is resolved.

One of the problems with extension methods...

Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 21):

You have redundant includes.  You only need the last include, which will include anything in that path.   Example:

```
var reports = _context.Reports
    .Include(rt => rt.Fields.Select(f => f.FieldType.FieldIdentifier));
```